# Function[] argument nesting for operations like Select[]

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

The following code selects a special element from a list

```
thelist = {"this", "notthis"};

Select[thelist, (# == "this") &]
```

What I want is a function which does just that and which takes lists (like *thelist*) and a string (like *"this"*) as argument. However I have a problem, because *Select* already uses an abstract function and so the naive idea

```
sel:=Select[#1, (# == #2) &]

sel[thelist,"this"]
```

doesn't work. This is really about the Function command and the problem might not just appear with *Select* but any abstract function nesting.

How to construct the object I need?

Comment: Something like : `Function[{x, y}, Select[x, # == y &]][thelist, "this"]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `With` to assign your string to a named variable and modify it as:

```
With[{str = #2}, Select[#, # == str &]] &[thelist, "this"]
(* {"this"} *)
```

Another option is to use a formal symbol in the inner pure function and replace it with your actual string

```
Select[#, (# == \[FormalS]) & /. \[FormalS] -> #2] &[thelist, "this"]
(* {"this"} *)
```

Alternately, if you wanted to do it solely with pure functions, you could do something like what b.gatessucks mentioned in the comments.

```
Function[{x, y}, Select[x, # == y &]][thelist, "this"]
(* {"this"} *)
```

Comment: `With` is exactly what I was going to suggest, +1. :P

Comment: Thanks, not using *#* and doing it like username b.gatessucks said in the comment was sufficient.

Comment: As another possible permutation of the code: `Select[#1, Function[test, test == #2]] &[thelist, "this"]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally done with `DownValues` definitions:

```
thelist = {"this", "notthis"};

sel[L_List, S_String] := Select[L, (# == S) &]

sel[thelist, "this"]
```

> ```
> {"this"}
> ```

Comment: Well, ... very true. I guess I was too much into a certain style of coding.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the Nearest[ ] function. This doesn't address the general issue, but does solve the specific question:

```
thelist = {"this", "notthis"};
Nearest[thelist, "this"]
```

Comment: `thelist = {"cat", "but", "hit"}; Nearest[thelist, "fat"]`... The example was just for illustration purposes, so merely addressing only the highly simplified case isn't very useful, IMO.

Comment: user, I agree with R.M in this case, but nevertheless welcome to the site and thanks for contributing.